# How to get the largest value in line

Tags: shell

In my project, the content of jobinfo.txt is:

```
3124631 nsgk138_LZH 48
3123498 nscc1697_ZJK 48
3115687 nsgg135_MJ 48
3123919 nscc1564_ZZG 840
3115689 nsgg135_MJ 48
3115690 nsgg135_MJ 48
3122716 nscc128_ZW 24
3122720 nscc128_ZW 24
3123868 nsgg038_PM 24
3122726 nscc128_ZW 24
```

I want to find the maxinum value of column 3, so i write a bb.sh, some content like this:

```
sendzabbixnum=`awk '{print $3}' jobinfo.txt |  sort -n  | uniq | tail -1`
echo $sendzabbixnum
awk '{if($3==$sendzabbixnum) print $0}' jobinfo.txt >> maxscalejobinfo.txt
```

It can display 840 in my terminal screen successfully, but in maxscalejobinfo.txt, there is nothing.

I can use in command line like this:

```
awk '{if($3==840) print $0}' jobinfo.txt
```

and get the correct result:

```
3123919 nscc1564_ZZG 840
```

I have tried in bb.sh:

```
awk '{if($3=="$sendzabbixnum") print $0}' jobinfo.txt >> maxscalejobinfo.txt
```

but it failed again

I tried another way in bb.sh:

```
awk '{if($3==840) print $0}' jobinfo.txt >> maxscalejobinfo.txt
```

it worked OK

what is wrong with bb.sh script? who can help me?

Comment: How about: `sort -g -k 3 jobinfo.txt|tail -n 1 >>maxscalejobinfo.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single awk for this instead of shell + awk:

```
awk '$NF > max {max=$NF; r=$0} END{print r > "maxscalejobinfo.txt"}' jobinfo.txt
```

Also make sure `jobinfo.txt` doesn't have DOS line ending by using:

```
cat -A jobinfo.txt
```

If you note `^M` in the end of each line then convert that file to Unix file first using `dos2unix` or `sed` or `tr`

Comment: Neat, I didn't know $NF would eval to the last field - I would have written it with $3 instead of $NF... I learn new things every day, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort command and redirect the output to maxscalejobinfo.txt

```
$ cat  jobinfo.txt
3124631 nsgk138_LZH 48
3123498 nscc1697_ZJK 48
3115687 nsgg135_MJ 48
3123919 nscc1564_ZZG 840
3115689 nsgg135_MJ 48
3115690 nsgg135_MJ 48
3122716 nscc128_ZW 24
3122720 nscc128_ZW 24
3123868 nsgg038_PM 24
3122726 nscc128_ZW 24

$ sort -k3 -nr jobinfo.txt | head -n 1
3123919 nscc1564_ZZG 840
```

Since this resembles SQL, you could do it with sqlite as well

```
$ cat ./sqllite_longline.sh
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 << EOF
create table t1(a,b,c);
.separator ' '
.import $1 t1
select * from t1 where t1.c=(select max(c) from t1)
EOF

$ ./sqllite_longline.sh jobinfo.txt
3123919 nscc1564_ZZG 840
```

Comment: Good use of `sort`. One disadvantage here: it sorts everything while only the top result is needed. On the other hand, if more than just that one are needed in the future then this would be the solution.  The `sqlite` one is interesting! (I haven't worked with it -- is it expensive by its start-up time?)

Comment: @zdim.. thanks for your review.. Yes, I'll also had the same reasons on sort.. reg sqlite.. just started working on this, not used heavily. You can have a look at question - 53957876 for a best example where I used sqllite..

Comment: Yes, that one is interesting, with even more benefit of SQL.  I am considering adding `sqlite` to some data-heavy production runs, so not to have to talk about adding tables etc to our (massive) Postgresql database.